# TableAdapter not updating to Access DataBase

Tags: vb.net, ms-access

```
Private Sub btnUpdate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnUpdate.Click
    Try
        Me.User_scoresTableAdapter.Insert(CStr(txtUser.Text), CStr(txtGame.Text), CDec(txtScore.Text), CDate(txtDate.Text))
        Me.User_scoresTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Game_timeDataSet4._User_scores)
        Me.User_scoresTableAdapter.Update(Me.Game_timeDataSet4._User_scores)
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Data Input Error")
    End Try
End Sub
```

This code is not updating to my Access database. I'm updating after it does the fill line.

Comment: Why are you blaming the `DataGridView`?  You are using a `TableAdapter` for the insert (not update) and the values come from controls?  Is that the real code?

Comment: Whoops thanks i meant the TableAdapter is updating to the database